# Ubuntu and OpenSUSE Dual Boot issue

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, opensuse

I've been trying to create a dual boot with OpenSUSE 11.1 and Ubuntu 9.04 and it has been giving me problems. I first install OpenSUSE which I believe formats the whole disk to ext3 by default, and that is what I did.

After OpenSUSE is finished installing, I install Ubuntu and try to do a specific partition, where I create an 8gb swap partition and the remaining space as my Ubuntu Partition. But I could not continue without create different mount point for each partition, which I make the Ubuntu Partition mount to (/), as I want Ubuntu as root, but keep the partition for OpenSUSE mount point the way it was, which was blank. I believe this is where the problem is, but I am uncertain.

After installing Ubuntu, it works completely fine, but when I reboot and log into OpenSuse, it's no longer bootable. I can not recall correctly, but the first error involved (/) which I believe is the root, and goes to the OpenSUSE login screen, which gives the same error when I attempt to login. I attempt to repair the problem with the OpenSuse CD, but the problem still lingers.

I attempt another reformat, but also did not end up successfully. I am attempting to do another reformat, but seeking advice before I do.

I've been thinking if I should make the SUSE parition mount point to (/boot), which would fix the problem.

Suggestions?

Comment: Please post here the output of sudo fdisk -l, the contents of both /etc/fstab files, the relevant /boot/grub/menu.lst and the precise error message you get when trying to boot suse.

Answer (score 1):

You need two ext3 partitions - one to mount as / on OpenSUSE and the second to use as / on Ubuntu. 
When you install OpenSUSE, create the following partitions

```
/dev/sda1 ext3  /
/dev/sda2 ext3  
/dev/sda3 swap
```

Do not mount */dev/sda2* in OpenSUSE, you'll use this as the / mount on Ubuntu. 
 We create the ext3 partition for Ubuntu upfront, so the Ubuntu installer does not have to resize the OpenSUSE ext3 partition to create its / mount point .

When installing Ubuntu, use */dev/sda2* as / mount:

```
/dev/sda1 ext3  
/dev/sda2 ext3  /
/dev/sda3 swap
```

Do not mount */dev/sda1* in Ubuntu.

The swap partition */dev/sda3* should be the same for both installs.

After you install Ubuntu, if you cannot see OpenSUSE in the grub boot menu list, you might need to edit */boot/grub/menu.lst* and add an entry for OpenSUSE.